# Why are fragment activities no longer available in Android 23?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am just curious about what happened to fragment activities in Android 23, why is it that a fragment activity no longer appear as an option when I want to create a new activity in Android Studio?

Comment: Why would you use `FragmentActivity` over `AppCompatActivity` anyway?

Comment: There used to be a "Fragment Activity" template. The maintainers of Android Studio revamped the templates recently and got rid of that particular template.

Answer (score 1):

It is still avaiable in [API 23](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please do some search before posting questions. It is exist but maybe it is not shown as creating option, try it yourself.

Check [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html).